# Recover Linux kernel

Tags: grub2, kernel

I once side loaded  Ubuntu 16.04, Windows 10 in BIOS mode. But then switched to UEFI mode to install  Ubuntu 18.04  and I saw

```
TSC_DEADLINE disabled due to Errdata; please upgrade microcode version to 0x22 or (later)
```

...some more text later

```
[ 202.364463] print_req_error: I/O error, dev loop0, sector 1347390
[ 211.112537] print_req_error: I/I error, dev sr0, sector 1436748
```

I restored to BIOS mode to continue with Ubuntu 16.04, Windows 10 but I saw

```
you must load kernel first  
not found: /boot/linux-kernel
```

when I chose Ubuntu from grub's options.
I have forgotten what I saw written, but it def had to do with the kernel missing. I looked for a solution which suggested using `boot repair` in a live CD, but I can't get Ubuntu to run without installing. I keep seeing the error in the as when trying to install.

My question? Where do I go from here I still want to install Ubuntu 18.04. I intended on removing everything to install Ubuntu.

Comment: Do you have other kernels installed?

Comment: Why do you need to side-load? If you have some strange hardware that prevents a normal install, please edit your question - that is important. Otherwise, use the normal, supported install process.

Comment: @RazorManager89 No. I'm not trying to side load, I switched to UEFI to clean install Ubuntu 18, then this showed up:   ```TSC_DEADLINE disabled due to Errdata; please upgrade microcode version to 0x22 or (later)```

Comment: As the line suggests, you should upgrade your intel microcode.